# WP + Google analytics = /search?

Tags: search, google-analytics

I finally found some time to tweak our business site. After digging some Google Analytic data I found out a portion of our users goes to "/search". Problem is: We don't offer a search function on our site as we aren't a webshop.

Does anyone know why or how Wordpress sends to /search? Is this when someone founds a 404 page or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search code comes with wordpress.If you remove search box it does not mean that search page is removed. If you want that google should not crawl your search page then you can specify in your robot.txt file like below :

Disallow: /search